# Java Swing Application Not Working Anymore

Tags: java, swing, class

I am pretty new to using swing, and I have a question. My code stopped working this morning, but I don't know why. I ran the debugger, and it says 2 lines of code. One is in the main class, one is in the other. They are both creating instances of each other.

The lines are something like this:
Main Class:

```
OnePlayerFrame OnePFrame = new OnePlayerFrame();
```

OnePlayerFrame Class:

```
MainFrame MainClass = new MainFrame();
```

I hope you can understand what I'm saying, as I said I'm pretty new to swing.

Thanks
-Matt

Ok, here is the whole thing:
Right, forgot to mention, I may have deleted a simple line of code and am overlooking it, so please stay calm if it's something simple :)

Main Class:

```
package rockpaperscissors;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MainFrame {

public JFrame frame = new JFrame();

private final ImageIcon rock = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Matthew/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RockPaperScissors/src/assets/rock.jpg");
private final ImageIcon paper = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Matthew/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RockPaperScissors/src/assets/paper.png");
private final ImageIcon scissors = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Matthew/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RockPaperScissors/src/assets/scissors.png");

private final JLabel rockLabel = new JLabel();
private final JLabel paperLabel = new JLabel();
private final JLabel scissorsLabel = new JLabel();

private final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
private final JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
private final JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
private final JPanel empty1 = new JPanel();
private final JPanel empty2 = new JPanel();
private final JPanel empty3 = new JPanel();
private final JPanel empty4 = new JPanel();
private final JPanel empty5 = new JPanel();

OnePlayerFrame OnePlayerFrame = new OnePlayerFrame();

public JButton btn1 = new JButton("1 Player");

private final JTextField text = new JTextField();

private final Font font = new Font("Showcard Gothic Regular", Font.BOLD, 28);


public MainFrame(){

    frame.setSize(360, 300);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(panel1);
    frame.add(panel2);
    frame.add(panel3);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    panel1.add(rockLabel);
    panel1.add(paperLabel);
    panel1.add(scissorsLabel);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3));
    panel2.add(empty1);
    panel2.add(empty2);
    panel2.add(empty3);
    panel2.add(empty4);
    panel2.add(btn1);
    panel2.add(empty5);

    panel3.add(text);
    panel3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    empty1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    empty2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    empty3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    empty4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    empty5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    text.setText("Rock Paper Scissors");
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(360, 80));
    text.setEditable(false);
    text.setBorder(null);
    text.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    text.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    rockLabel.setIcon(rock);
    paperLabel.setIcon(paper);
    scissorsLabel.setIcon(scissors);

    btn1.setFocusPainted(false);

    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            frame.dispose();
            OnePlayerFrame.startGame1();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainFrame();
}
}
```

And here is the second class:

```
package rockpaperscissors;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class OnePlayerFrame {

MainFrame MainClass = new MainFrame();

JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();

JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel6 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel7 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel8 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel9 = new JPanel();
JPanel empty1 = new JPanel();
JPanel empty2 = new JPanel();

JTextField playerText1 = new JTextField();
JTextField playerText2 = new JTextField();
JTextField playerText3 = new JTextField();
JTextField compText1 = new JTextField();
JTextField compText2 = new JTextField();
JTextField compText3 = new JTextField();
JTextField pChoose = new JTextField();
JTextField cChoose = new JTextField();

JButton btn1 = new JButton("Rock");
JButton btn2 = new JButton("Paper");
JButton btn3 = new JButton("Scissors");
JButton btn4 = new JButton("Confirm");
JButton btn5 = new JButton("Fight!");
JButton getB = new JButton();

JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
JLabel label2 = new JLabel();

boolean confirmed = false;
boolean hasSelected = false;
boolean runThread = true;



String playerMove;



ImageIcon playerIcon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Matthew/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RockPaperScissors/src/assets/question-mark.jpg");
ImageIcon computerIcon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Matthew/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RockPaperScissors/src/assets/question-mark.jpg");

Font font = new Font("Showcard Gothic Regular", Font.BOLD, 18);

public OnePlayerFrame(){

    gameFrame.setVisible(true);
    gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gameFrame.setSize(500, 400);
    gameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(MainClass.frame);
    gameFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    gameFrame.add(panel1);
    gameFrame.add(panel2);
    gameFrame.add(panel3);
    MainClass.frame.dispose();



    panel1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
    panel1.add(panel4);
    panel1.add(panel5);
    panel1.add(panel6);
    panel1.add(panel7);

    panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    panel2.add(pChoose);
    panel2.add(panel8);
    panel2.add(btn4);

    panel3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel3.add(cChoose);
    panel3.add(panel9);
    panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

    panel4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel4.add(playerText1);
    panel4.add(playerText2);
    panel4.add(playerText3);
    panel4.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

    panel5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel5.add(label1);

    panel6.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel6.add(label2);

    panel7.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel7.add(compText1);
    panel7.add(compText2);
    panel7.add(compText3);
    panel7.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

    panel8.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    panel8.add(btn1);
    panel8.add(btn2);
    panel8.add(btn3);

    panel9.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    panel9.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel9.add(empty1);
    panel9.add(btn5);
    panel9.add(empty2);



    empty1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    empty2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



    playerText1.setEditable(false);
    playerText1.setBorder(null);
    playerText1.setText("Player");
    playerText1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    playerText1.setFont(font);
    playerText1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

    playerText2.setEditable(false);
    playerText2.setBorder(null);
    playerText2.setText("Chose");
    playerText2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    playerText2.setFont(font);
    playerText2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

    playerText3.setEditable(false);
    playerText3.setBorder(null);
    playerText3.setText("====>");
    playerText3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    playerText3.setFont(font);
    playerText3.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

    compText1.setEditable(false);
    compText1.setBorder(null);
    compText1.setText("Computer");
    compText1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    compText1.setFont(font);
    compText1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

    compText2.setEditable(false);
    compText2.setBorder(null);
    compText2.setText("Chose");
    compText2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    compText2.setFont(font);
    compText2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

    compText3.setEditable(false);
    compText3.setBorder(null);
    compText3.setText("<====");
    compText3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    compText3.setFont(font);
    compText3.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

    pChoose.setEditable(false);
    pChoose.setBorder(null);
    pChoose.setText("Choose your move");
    pChoose.setFont(font);
    pChoose.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    pChoose.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    cChoose.setEditable(false);
    cChoose.setBorder(null);
    cChoose.setText("Computer is choosing");
    cChoose.setFont(font);
    cChoose.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    cChoose.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



    btn1.setRolloverEnabled(true);
    btn1.setFocusPainted(false);

    btn2.setFocusPainted(false);
    btn2.setRolloverEnabled(true);

    btn3.setFocusPainted(false);
    btn3.setRolloverEnabled(true);

    btn4.setFocusPainted(false);
    btn4.setRolloverEnabled(true);

    btn5.setFocusPainted(false);
    btn5.setRolloverEnabled(true);
    btn5.setVisible(false);
    btn5.setFont(font);



    label1.setIcon(playerIcon);

    label2.setIcon(computerIcon);
}

public void startGame1(){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(confirmed == true || confirmed == false){
                if(confirmed == false){
                    try{
                        if(confirmed == false){
                            cChoose.setText("Computer is choosing");
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        }
                        if(confirmed == false){
                            cChoose.setText("Computer is choosing.");
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        }
                        if(confirmed == false){
                            cChoose.setText("Computer is choosing..");
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        }
                        if(confirmed == false){
                            cChoose.setText("Computer is choosing...");
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        gameFrame.dispose();
                    }
                }
                if(confirmed == true){
                    cChoose.setText("Computer has chosen!");
                    fightButtonSet();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();


    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if(confirmed == false){
                playerMove = btn1.getText();
                hasSelected = true;
                pChoose.setText("You have selected rock");
                getB = btn1;
            }
            else{
                pChoose.setText("You have already confirmed " + getB.getText().toLowerCase() + "!");
            }
        }
    });

    btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if(confirmed == false){
                playerMove = btn2.getText();
                hasSelected = true;
                pChoose.setText("You have selected paper");
                getB = btn2;
            }
            else{
                pChoose.setText("You have already confirmed " + getB.getText().toLowerCase() + "!");
            }
        }
    });

    btn3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if(confirmed == false){
                playerMove = btn3.getText();
                hasSelected = true;
                pChoose.setText("You have selected scissors");
                getB = btn3;
            }
            else{
                pChoose.setText("You have already confirmed " + getB.getText().toLowerCase() + "!");
            }
        }
    });

    btn4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if(hasSelected == true && confirmed == false){
                confirmed = true;
                pChoose.setText("You have confirmed " + getB.getText().toLowerCase() + "!");
                cChoose.setText("Computer has chosen!");

            }
            else{
                if(hasSelected == false){
                    pChoose.setText("You haven't selected anything yet!");
                }
                else if (confirmed == true){
                    pChoose.setText("You have already confirmed " + getB.getText().toLowerCase() + "!");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public void fightButtonSet(){

    btn5.setVisible(true);
    btn5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            FIGHT();
        }
    });
}

public void FIGHT(){
    if(getB.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")){

    }
    if(getB.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")){

    }
    if(getB.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")){

    }
}



}
```

Comment: Paste mor code please.

Comment: Well, your code is "not working anymore" and the two lines **might** be related to the problem. Do you seriously think that's enough to get help?

Comment: more code please. mucho more codz

Comment: More code - currently pasted code is potentially bug free ; )

Comment: Sorry, I was just about to. Also, sorry if it's a bit messy

Comment: You have `StackOverflowError` i guess..

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: The JFrames wouldn't open but it's all fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can abstract a little you have this.

```
public class TestCircularDependency {

    static class A{

        B b = new B();

        }

        static class B{

        A a = new A();

        }

        public static void main(String args[]){

            A a = new A();

        }

}
```

This will throw a `StackOverflowError`. You have a circular dependency. The problem is that you are instance each one in constructor then you have infinite recursion.

In java you can have circular dependency but not in object creation. You can do something like this.

```
public class TestCircularDependency {

    static class A{

        B b;

        }

        static class B{

        A a;

        }

        public static void main(String args[]){

            A a = new A();
            a.b = new B();
            b.a= a;
        }

}
```